# Modus ponens and modus tollens with embedded conditionals

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is the most concise/straightforward way to formulate modus ponens and modus tollens arguments when embedded conditionals are involved?

Is the formulation below correct (for modus ponens)?

(A) ⊃ B ⊃ C ⊃ D ⊃ E ⊃ F

A

B

C

D

E

Conclusion: F

Similarly, is the formulation below correct (for modus tollens)?

A ⊃ B ⊃ C ⊃ D ⊃ E ⊃ (F)

˜F

˜E

˜D

˜C

˜B

Conclusion: ˜A

Comment: It depends on the associativity of the implication operator. With the usual interpretation, your first one is corrent while the second one is not.

Comment: There is no universal convention regarding [Operator Precedence of Logical operators](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/glossary/operator_precedence.html): "When an operand is surrounded by operators of equal precedence, the operand associates to the right. "

Comment: If so, the first formula is : $(A) ⊃ (B ⊃ (C ⊃ (D ⊃ (E ⊃ F))))$. Thus, applying MP with premise $A$ you get: $(B ⊃ (C ⊃ (D ⊃ (E ⊃ F))))$ and so on.

Comment: The second one will be: $(A ⊃( B ⊃ (C ⊃ (D ⊃ E)))) ⊃ (F)$ and applying MT with premise $\lnot F$ you will get: $\lnot (A ⊃( B ⊃ (C ⊃ (D ⊃ E)))) $

Answer (score 1):

Modus Tollens can be "reduced" to Modus Ponens via [Contaposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition):

> from $p \to q$ we have $\lnot q \to \lnot p$ by Contraposition, and with premise $\lnot q$ we conclude to $\lnot p$ by MP.

When we have nested conditionals, like: $(p \to r) \to q$, we can derive in the same way: $\lnot (p \to r)$, bu the next move with $\lnot r$ will be blocked.

Specifically, $\lnot (p \to r)$ and $\lnot r$ will not imply $\lnot p$, as you can easily verify with the truth assignment: $v(p)=\text T$ and $v(r)=\text F$.